# TortoisHg unable to update and merge outstanding uncommitted changes

Tags: version-control, mercurial, repository, version, versioning

Hi this is my first project with mercurial, i know much better tortoise svn. I have problem that can't merge changes from others having error: abort: outstanding uncommitted changes [image]

what can I do ?

Ok i finally merged and now there is red line what does it mean?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have uncommitted changes you need to commit or discard them before merging.

Comment: ok now i have untracked files in working directory differ from files in requested revision

Comment: can u take a look one more time on second image please? i merged the files and now I am missing for some files and there is this red line.

Comment: The red line was there even before merging. And no, I have no idea how TortoiseHG paints branch lines.